# Setting focus of cursor back to Python

Tags: python, tkinter, os.system

I have a little program that uses TKinter to open a csv. 
All works fine.

When the user chooses a file, I want the cursor and the active window to return to the Python shell.

I am using this:

```
os.system('''/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to set frontmost of process "Python" to true' ''')
```

When in IDLE, this works, when the program runs, but when I just double click the .py file and run it in the Python Shell, it says it can't find the path.

Anyone know the path I need?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Further research and this is my solution.

```
import win32gui as wg
from win32gui import GetWindowText, GetForegroundWindow

#This gets the details of the current window, the one running the program
aw = (GetForegroundWindow())

#Do some stuff..

#This tells the program to set the focus on the captured window
wg.SetForegroundWindow(aw)
```

I hope this helps anyone else looking for the same thing I was. 
:-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it refers to the running process via pid so it shouldn't matter exactly how you ran it:

```
import os
pid = os.getpid()
os.system("""/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to set frontmost of (first process whose unix id is %d) to true'""" % pid)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. 

I get the same result. 
Once I close the "Choose File" window, the cursor is not present in any window and the Python shell returns an error of  "Could not locate path"

Comment: I might see if i can get win32gui to work, but I cant seem to get it to install.

Comment: Oh, I was assuming that you were on a Mac, given that you were trying a purely Mac-specific solution.

Comment: Commands are Unix based, Powershell ion windows will support most of them, its why my previous "Finder" code worked ok. 

I guess the issue is its not great to use it, as it is kinda more for mac. 
I got Win32Gui to work. 

But thanks for the help anyway.